# Trouble replacing wrapped (non-NuGet) assembly with NuGet package in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, asp.net-core-1.0

I've run into an issue while developing a ASP.NET Core app. I needed to step through the execution of one of my NuGet libraries so I forked the repo and added a reference to the local DLL and PDB files. With the new awesomeness of .NET Core, this results in VS creating a wrapper project and copying the resources into local `lib` folder local to the project.

This worked great and I was able to step through the code and debug my issue. However, now I am attempting to revert back to the NuGet package but it seems that some VS caching is preventing the package from being retrieved from NuGet. The issue seems to be for the entire solution as none of the projects in my solution are able to successfully install the package. Creating a new Solution and installing the package from the Package Manager does work as expected.

**Observations**

After deleting the `wrap\project.json` and `lib\*` assets, I am experiencing the following:

1. When I attempt to install the package in the project which was previously referencing the local "wrapped" assembly, I get the following error in the references node of the project:

> NU1002 The dependency BrockAllen.MembershipReboot 1.0.0 in project [...] does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1

2. When I attempt to install the NuGet package in another project in the solution (which did not previously reference the wrapped assembly), I get a different error:

> NU1001 The dependency BrockAllen.MembershipReboot >= 8.4.0 could not be resolved.

3. When I initiate the **Add Reference...** dialog from the project which previously reference the wrapped assembly, I get the following VS error dialog:

> Could not find part of the path 'C:[SolutionDir]\wrap\BrockAllen.MembershipReboot`.

I find that bit particularly interesting because it's obviously holding on to that reference somewhere... If anyone has any insights into how to resolve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it. I am trying to avoid having to port to a new solution but that's likely my next step.

**Further Details*

I've done a text search through the solution directory but found nothing which still references the `wrap` dir except the `global.json` which just looks like this:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "wrap"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

The `project.json` file for the project is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "SolutionForms.Service.Providers Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Vinney" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "SolutionForms.Data": "1.0.0-*",
        "AutoMapper": "4.1.1"      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "BrockAllen.MembershipReboot": "8.4.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "RavenDB.Embedded": "3.0.30037"
  }
}
```

I have cleared some local AppData folders, namely: `%AppData%\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs` and `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to get a little closer. I found that the `project.lock.json` file was holding on to the local assembly reference. By running `dnu restore` I was able to release those old references. However, I found that I was having to continually run the command after uninstalling and re-installing the package. And, ultimately, after I got my references to install without error, I still got compilation errors on the dependency line in `project.json`. There is still something holding on to that reference.

I'm reverting to rebuilding my solution and project files :(